# Iterate through several files in bash

Tags: bash

I have a folder with several files that are named like this:

file.001.txt.gz, file.002.txt.gz,  ... ,  file.150.txt.gz

What I want to do is use a loop to run a program with each file. I was thinking in something like this (just a sketch):

```
for i in {1:150}
  gunzip file.$i.txt.gz
  ./my_program file.$i.txt output.$1.txt
  gzip file.$1.txt
```

First of all, I don't know if something like this is gonna work, and second, I can't figure out how to keep the three digits numeration the file have ('001' instead of just '1').

Thanks a lot

Comment: You need to change 'output.$1.txt' to 'output.$i.txt' as a first step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for ranges in bash is

```
{1..150}
```

not `{1:150}`.

Moreover, if your bash is recent enough, you can add the leading zeroes:

```
{001..150}
```

The correct syntax of the for loop needs `do` and `done`.

```
for i in {001..150} ; do
    # ...
done
```

It's unclear what `$1` contains in your script.

Answer (score 1):

To iterate over files I believe the simpler way is:
(assuming there are no files named 'file.*.txt' already in the directory and that your output file can have a different name)

```
for i in file.*.txt.gz; do
    gunzip $i
    ./my_program $i $i-output.txt
    gzip file.*.txt
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `find` command:

```
# Path to the source directory
dir="./"

while read file
do
  output="$(basename "$file")"
  output="$(dirname "$file")/"${output/#file/output}
  echo "$file ==> $output"
done < <(find "$dir" \
  -regextype 'posix-egrep' \
  -regex '.*file\.[0-9]{3}\.txt\.gz$')
```

The same via pipe:

```
find "$dir" \
  -regextype 'posix-egrep' \
  -regex '.*file\.[0-9]{3}\.txt\.gz$' | \
  while read file
  do
    output="$(basename "$file")"
    output="$(dirname "$file")/"${output/#file/output}
    echo "$file ==> $output"
  done
```

*Sample output*

```
/home/ruslan/tmp/file.001.txt.gz ==> /home/ruslan/tmp/output.001.txt.gz
/home/ruslan/tmp/file.002.txt.gz ==> /home/ruslan/tmp/output.002.txt.gz
```

(for `$dir=/home/ruslan/tmp/`).

*Description*

The scripts iterate the files in `$dir` directory. The `$file` variable is filled with the next line read from the `find` command.
The `find` command returns a list of paths corresponding to the regular expression `'.*file\.[0-9]{3}\.txt\.gz$'`.

The `$output` variable is built from two parts: *basename* (path without directories) and *dirname* (path to file's directory).

`${output/#file/output}` expression replaces *file* with *output* at the front end of `$output` variable (*see [Manipulating Strings](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html)*)

Answer (score 0):

Try-

```
for i in $(seq -w 1 150)     #-w adds the leading zeroes
do
  gunzip file."$i".txt.gz
  ./my_program file."$i".txt output."$1".txt
  gzip file."$1".txt
done
```

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for ranges is [as choroba said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40153151/418413), but when iterating over files you usually want to use a glob. If you know all the files have three digits in their names you can match on digits:

```
shopt -s nullglob
for i in file.0[0-9][0-9].txt.gz file.1[0-4][0-9] file.15[0].txt.gz; do
  gunzip file.$i.txt.gz
  ./my_program file.$i.txt output.$i.txt
  gzip file.$i.txt
done
```

This will only iterate through files that exist. If you use the range expression, you have to take extra care not to try to operate on files that don't exist.

```
for i in file.{000..150}.txt.gz; do
    [[ -e "$i" ]] || continue
    ...otherstuff
done
```